# How do I let a user send an admin an email

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using ASP.NET MVC for a project. Currently, I would like to make a page with a bootstrap form that a user could fill out, click send, then an email will be sent to the target email. For some reason I cannot accomplish this.

This is my `Email.cshtml` file that presents the user with a form. Asks them for their email, a subject, and the message. There is a send button at the bottom.

```html
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Email";
}

<h2>Send Me An Email!</h2>


<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="ProcessFile.cshtml">
    <fieldset>

        <!-- Student email form-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="textinput">Student Email</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input id="studentEmail" name="studentEmail" type="text" placeholder="Enter Here" class="form-control input-md" required="">

            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Email subject form-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="textinput">Subject</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input id="emailSubject" nameemailSubjectsubject" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="">

            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Message for email -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="textarea">Message</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="emailMessage" name="emailMessage" style="width:600px; height:200px; resize: none;"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Send button -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="sendbutton"></label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input id="sendbutton" name="sendbutton" class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Send">
            </div>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I have this redirect them to a page called `ProcessFile.cshtml`. The code for it is below. For some reason the `Request` context isn't showing and has a red underline where it cannot find context. What am I doing wrong? Is there an easier route for what I am trying to accomplish?

```
var studentEmail = Request["studentEmail"];
var emailSubject = Request["emailSubject"];
var emailMessage = Request["emailMessage"];
```

```html
@using System.Web.Helpers;

@{
    var studentEmail = Request["studentEmail"];
    var emailSubject = Request["emailSubject"];
    var emailMessage = Request["emailMessage"];
    var errorMessage = "";
    var debuggingFlag = false;

    try
    {
        // Initialize WebMail helper
        WebMail.SmtpServer = "your-SMTP-host";
        WebMail.SmtpPort = 25;
        WebMail.UserName = "your-user-name-here";
        WebMail.Password = "your-account-password";
        WebMail.From = "your-email-address-here";

        // Attach file and send email
        WebMail.Send(to: studentEmail, subject: emailSubject, body: emailMessage);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        errorMessage = ex.Message;
    }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Request for Assistance</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Sorry to hear that you are having trouble, <b>Dad</b>.</p>
    @if (errorMessage == "")
    {
        <p><b>Dad</b>, thank you for your interest.</p>
        <p>
            An email message has been sent to our dad service
            department
        </p>
    }
    else
    {
        <p><b>The email was <em>not</em> sent.</b></p>
        <p>
            Please check that the code in the ProcessRequest page has
            correct settings for the SMTP server name, a user name,
            a password, and a "from" address.
        </p>
        if (debuggingFlag)
        {
            <p>The following error was reported:</p>
            <p><em>@errorMessage</em></p>
        }
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't understand the [MVC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7Voso411Vs) concept. You are doing controller's (C in MV**C**) work in view (V in M**V**C) which is bad.

Comment: Please only provide feedback that is helpful

Comment: Well, are you using `MVC` or are you doing [`ASP.Net Web Pages`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/) (they're different flavors of ASP.net)? Your code is identical to this [`ASP.Net Web Pages sample`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/11-adding-email-to-your-web-site)? It matters because even some defaults in `MVC` don't allow you to invoke `.cshtml` - which you have in your `<form action=... />` (which also means you're not "redirecting" nor using any "routing" in what you have posted).